# What methods - inspired by Haavelmo’s Structural Econometrics - can show that a partial equilibrium model is unreliable?

Tags: statistics, modeling, econometrics, macro

According to Spanos 2014 [Revisiting Haavelmo's Structural econometrics: Bridging the gap between theory and data](https://secure.hosting.vt.edu/www.econ.vt.edu/directory/spanos/spanos9.pdf) Dynamic Stochastic General Equilibrium models are statistically inadequate, in such an order of magnitude as to render them useless.

> The most serious problem with DSGE models is that they are often
>   statistically inadequate. Advocates of DSGE modeling, however, have
>   put forward a number of arguments to explain away the unreliability of
>   their evidence, such as ‘the price one has to pay for rigorous and
>   policy-relevant theoretical models’ (Lucas, 1980, p. 696), or simply
>   inevitable: “The models constructed within this theoretical
>   framework are necessarily highly abstract. Consequently, they are
>   necessarily false, and statistical hypothesis testing will reject
>   them. This does not imply, however, that nothing can be learned from
>   such quantitative theoretical exercises.” (Prescott, 1986, p. 10)

Part of my research involves using a partial equilibrium models to simulate a particular segment of an economy.

Considering the above, I would like to illustrate failure of a partial equilibrium model. What methods would you use to show that a given equilibrium model is statistically unreliable?

Comment: This looks like it might belong on http://economics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have added this question there:http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/what-methods-inspired-by-haavelmo-s-structural-econometrics-can-show-that-a  I don't know how to close a question here. So I keep if for the record.

Comment: Hi Paul4forest, welcome to Quant.SE! I believe this question could have been on-topic here but since we tryh to keep questions unique across the StackExchange network I'm going to close it here. In the future you can request a migration and the question can then be moved by a moderator such as me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has been cross posted to economics.

Comment: Alright I didn't know migration was possible. Thanks.